# Detox: App has not responded to the network requests below

Tags: jestjs, detox, jest-circus

Running detox 17.4.3 with Jest-Circus as the test runner I am running into the following error using an iOS simulator.

```
detox[18766] WARN:  [Client.js/PENDING_REQUESTS] App has not responded to the network requests below:
  (id = -1000) isReady: {}

Unresponded network requests might result in timeout errors in Detox tests.
```

Here are the versions of Jest in my package.json.

```
 "jest": "^26.4.1",

 "jest-circus": "^26.4.1",
```

Any ideas how I can debug this further or a fix?

Comment: Any luck here? Having the same problem

Comment: @RomainBraun No I never got past it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case: As of 18.0.0 (December 2020) Detox requires you to call `device.launchApp()` or all your tests will time out because the app didn't launch.  See the [migration guide](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Migration.md).

Unfortunately this isn't documented in the [release notes](https://github.com/wix/Detox/releases/tag/18.0.0) or suggested in error messages - opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/2645) to suggest clearer documentation.